# How to show the state of a checkbox with used 'linkState' in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use `linkState` for a checkbox, but I found I can't get the state back and show it:

```
var Item = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      ok: true
    }
  },
  render: function() {
     return (
     <div>
       <input type="checkbox" checkedLink={this.linkState('ok')} />
       Is it OK: [{this.state.ok}]
       </div>
     )
  }
});
React.render(<Item />, document.body);
```

The key line is:

```
Is it OK: [{this.state.ok}]
```

But the state is not shown. Is it correct to use `this.state.ok` to show it?

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/detese/2/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main code is correct, the actual problem is with how you're debugging the code.

- `<div>{true}</div>` renders as `<div>true</div>`
- `<div>{false}</div>` renders as `<div></div>`

To just drop state into a component's render I use this snippet:

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4)}</pre>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fazapisocu/2/edit?html,js,output)

If you have a boolean and want to render the string representation, do `String(thatBoolean)`.  React will always render your string exactly as you tell it to, but there are quite a few edge cases for non-string values.